# asmx json serialization vs. wcf json serialization

Tags: vb.net, wcf, json, serialization, asmx

I have two experimental web services. One is an asmx contained within a .net web application. The other is a WCF service library being invoked from the web application.

The asmx basically does everything I need, but I think WCF would be better, except that it doesn't do anything as I would expect after fiddling with the asmx service.

For example, the same method behaves differently in each:

```
' ASMX
<WebMethod(BufferResponse:=True, EnableSession:=False)>
Function Test(aObject as Object) as Object
  ' object will have been successfully serializaed into a dictionary
  Dim lResult as SomeObject = new SomeObject(aObject)
  return lResult ' lResult will be serialized as whatever type it is and will be deserialized by client making ajax call
End Function

' WCF
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(RequestFormat:=ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat:=ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)>
Function Test(aObject As Object) As Object
  ' object is serialized as an empty instance of Object
  ' not very useful
  Dim lResult as SomeObject = new SomeObject(aObject) ' waste of time with useless object
  return lResult ' even if lResult could be instantiated the client returns error 500 because 
                 ' WCF won't serialize SomeObject as Object
End Function
```

I've been researching this problem off and on for several months as I have time between projects. Nothing I've tried makes WCF do what ASMX does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I see it is that you create WCF services to a specific Interface contract.

If you can just specify any type of Object, then there is no programmatic mechanism to validate that either end of the pipe has correctly implemented that Interface.

I have found WCF to be generally much more restrictive than ASMX in terms of class serialization and deserialization, but switching to WCF from ASMX has tremendously improved our applications in terms of stability, maintainability, and productivity.

Having said that, there is no reason to switch to WCF just because it is WCF. You need to identify exactly why you think it is better for your situation and, if it is, then you need to create some test cases using actual classes instead of just Objects to verify that it will meet your needs.

One thing to think about: if you are consuming WCF services in your own .Net applications written in Silverlight, WPF, or WinForms, then WCF will make your life a lot easier in the long run because it makes it possible to share the same business object class code on both ends of the pipe.

**Update with info from comments**

Actually, you can serialize abstract classes as long as they can be deserialized to concrete implementations. You can do this by attributing the abstract class with the KnownType attribute for each of the concrete classes that you want to serialize.

The primary issue is not the service interface contract, it is the DataContract which requires a concrete class at some point. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) describes the rules.

You could create a catchall class that inherits from object and is decorated with known type for the classes you want to use.

Comment: We're using ajax/json to interact with the service from the web browser.  I want to go with WCF for a number of reasons, but I need the ability to pass an object. It is still an explicit contract. WCF won't even work if we want to pass an abstract ancestor other than Object.

Comment: @MarkLauter: Actually, you can serialize abstract classes as long as they can be deserialized to concrete implementations. You can do this by attributing the abstract class with the KnownType attribute for each of the concrete classes that you want to serialize. The primary issue is not the service interface contract, it is the DataContract which requires a concrete class at some point. This link describes the rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx. You could create a catchall class that inherits from object and is decorated with known type for the classes you want to use

Comment: Yeah, buddy! See my post below for the full solution based on the direction you pointed us in. Thanks very much for the help, and I would sure up-vote you if I could, but you're in a comment instead of answer section.

Comment: @MarkLauter: That's great news! Since the comments were on the answer that I originally provided, I have updated the answer with the relevant comments. So maybe an upvote? :)

Comment: I didn't notice you were the original poster, hah! Up-voted as promissed. Man, our whole team is jazzed. We've been working on this off and on for weeks as we've had little bits of time here and there. You're comment really provided the key. Within a few hours of experimentation we had the solution just posted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We added a function that returns all the types, including a List(of T) for each type, that fit our desired criteria - objects that may be stored in our cache. As long as we tag the ICacheable types in our *.Core assembly with the IsCacheableAttribute they'll be returned in the list and we don't need a hard coded KnownType list that's impossible to maintain. We also added the property d to hold the data, which hopefully does the same thing for security in the browser/client the Microsoft .d does.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports OurCompany.Cache
Imports OurApplication.Core

<DataContract(), KnownType("AllTypes")>
Public Class Data

    Private Shared mCacheableType As Type = GetType(ICacheable)
    Private Shared mIsCachedAttribute As Type = GetType(IsCacheableAttribute)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property d As Object

    Private Shared Function AllTypes() As IEnumerable(Of Type)
        Return GetCacheableTypesFromAssembly(GetType(AssemblyKeyClass).Assembly)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetCacheableTypesFromAssembly(aAssembly As Assembly) As IEnumerable(Of Type)
        Dim lTypes As List(Of Type) = aAssembly.GetTypes().Where(Function(t) IsCacheable(t)).ToList
        Dim lTypes2 As List(Of Type) = New List(Of Type)
        lTypes2.AddRange(lTypes)
        For Each lType In lTypes2
            Dim lListType As Type = GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType({lType})
            lTypes.Add(lListType)
        Next
        Return lTypes
    End Function

    Private Shared Function IsCacheable(aType As Type) As Boolean
        Dim lResult As Boolean = False
        If aType.GetInterfaces.Contains(mCacheableType) Then
            Dim lAttribute As Object() = aType.GetCustomAttributes(mIsCachedAttribute, True)
            If lAttribute.Count = 1 Then
                lResult = DirectCast(lAttribute(0), IsCacheableAttribute).Value
            End If
        End If
        Return lResult
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's the IService method we used to test returning various types of data.

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(RequestFormat:=ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat:=ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Function Test() As Data
```

As for passing data to the service, we'll just stick with passing a String and using the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize it.  This way we preserve the "unknown object to dictionary" behavior we're counting on for some complex types.

Comment: We've since abandoned the object to dictionary behavior and are able to pass even complex types correctly using the known types idea.

Answer (score 1):

Minor change removes coupling to the application namespace and allows us to use this class as part of our base library collection. We turned Data into a generic type. This sure beats typing KnownType(GetType(YetAnotherClass)) hundreds of times and then every time we add a new json transportable class to the system.

```
<DataContract(), KnownType("AllTypes")>
Public NotInheritable Class Data(Of T)

    Private Shared Function AllTypes() As IEnumerable(Of Type)
        Return GetSerializableTypesFromAssembly(GetType(T).Assembly)
    End Function
```